# Social Network in Rails - which framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-networking

Should I use:

1. Community Engine
2. Insoshi
3. LovdByLess
4. RailsSpace
5. Roll-my-own

I am looking to quickly get a social network up with support for mobile browsing. While I'm familiar with Ruby & Rails, I am not an expert (have built some basic Rails apps, have written a bunch of Ruby programs for enterprise integration).

Thanks, skybison

Comment: Here's another that may be worth checking out: http://www.enginey.com/

I've been working roll-my-own myself. Lot's of fun!

Answer (score 2):

insoshi is quite ok, i used it in a past project. although i can also recommend rolling your own, which is not such a big problem with all the existing gems out there. i can recommend starting with authlogic (authentication) - then paperclip (attachments). all the other stuff is best rolled on your own. have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say make you own. I tried community engine and Lovdbyless, but mostly it didn't have what I wanted and had too much of what I didn't have.

So I created my own, mostly from what this screencast. It has most of the self-referential relationships to users can follow,unfollow and other stuff.

http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/creating-a-twitter-clone-in-rails-part-1

Answer (score 0):

I used community-engine but and really had a lot of features which i don't wanted and had to extend. It is easily extend-able because it is a plugin and you can extend or override different parts of that. But i found a much cooler plugin called tog http://www.toghq.com/ which is fully plugin based, so you can roll your very own setup of features and you can build your social network from "bricks". Also has a lot of plugins to tog which can be used unobstrusively. I think this is far the best.