# Any Ruby on Rails equivalent to Pinax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, social-networking, pinax

Pinax is:

> An integrated collection of Django
>   applications that provides the most
>   commonly needed social networking
>   features, including openID support,
>   email verification, site
>   announcements, user-to-user messaging,
>   friend invitations, interest groups
>   with discussions, wikis, and more.

[Cloud27](http://cloud27.com/) is a demonstration of [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/)

**Any equivalent in Ruby on Rails?**

Comment: This question may help, too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320/best-ruby-on-rails-social-networking-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you also want to take a look at the following entry on stackoverflow that has a similar topic: [Social Network in Rails - which framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072546/social-network-in-rails-which-framework/2076824#2076824)